# how to avoid foreach loop in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm facing a problem in a PHP code, I built a weekly scholar calendar as a form of a table of five columns that represents "hours" and in the first column I set "days" of a calendar. I used 7 classes and my code is already working and It's displaying days and hours exactly what I like to BUT I have a problem with inserting dates , I used foreach loop to get days and to duplicate two checkboxes and a label into the four columns of "hours" ; so when I insert data ; and I go to MySQL platform I got all seven days of the current week inserted in. I don't know if I explained well. Codes are little bit complicated and long, I'll join only the foreach code that I think is the source of problems in this code.

```
<tbody  action="week.php">
<tr> 
    <th>
        <?php foreach($currentWeek->days() as $day ): ?>
        <?php  echo $day->name() ?> <?php  echo $day->int()?> <?php  echo $firstDay->month()->name()?>
    </th>
    <td>
        <form method="post">
        <input  type="checkbox" name="abs" value="Absence">Absence<input  type="checkbox" name="abs" value="delay">delay
        <input  type="text" name="justify" placeholder="Justify  the absence" minlength="2" required autofocus></th>
        <button type="submit" name="enreg1">Validate</button> </form> 
        <?php 
            echo $day;
        ?>
        <?php 
            if(isset($_REQUEST['enreg1'])){
                    if($day == NOW())
                    {$sql="INSERT INTO absence(cne,date,seance1,justif1) 
                          VALUES('1234','".$day."','".$_POST["abs"]."','".$_POST["justify"]."');";  
                    $res=$conn->prepare($sql);
                    $res->execute();
                    $res->closeCursor();} 
                    }
        ?>
    </td>   
    <td>
        <form method="post">
        <input  type="checkbox" name="abs" value="Absence">Absence<input  type="checkbox" name="abs" value="delay">delay
        <input  type="text" name="justify" placeholder="Justify  the absence" minlength="2" required autofocus></th>
        <button type="submit" name="enreg2">Validate</button> </form> 

        <?php echo $day;        
         ?></td>
    <td>
        <form method="post">
        <input  type="checkbox" name="abs" value="Absence">Absence<input  type="checkbox" name="abs" value="delay">delay
        <input  type="text" name="justify" placeholder="Justify  the absence" minlength="2" required autofocus></th>
        <button type="submit" name="enreg3">Validate</button> </form> 

        <?php 
        echo $day; ?></td>
    <td>
        <form method="post">
        <input  type="checkbox" name="abs" value="Absence">Absence<input  type="checkbox" name="abs" value="delay">delay
        <input  type="text" name="justify" placeholder="Justify  the absence" minlength="2" required autofocus></th>
        <button type="submit" name="enreg4">Validate</button> </form> 

        <?php 
        echo $day; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <th>
        <?php endforeach ?>

    </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: try json_encode or serializing $day object before inserting into db.

Comment: I tried to edit your question but I see many open and close HTML tags in wrong place. I would suggest cleaning your code before posting question.

Comment: Html code doesn't matters in this case and I'm sure that It's correct ; I have problem in foreach loop that I used above to get a static table , the problem is all the static changes are written is mysql database but I want to insert the only the row that I've checked in that checkbox

Comment: You're missing a ; from the end of endforeach